# Android custom button listener not getting called

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom ImageButton and I want to change it's image on click. So far I havent been able to get the onClick method inside the button to perform it's action.

```
public class FlashButtonView extends ImageButton{
private Drawable mFlashOffSrc, mFlashOnSrc, mFlashAutoSrc;
private Drawable mCurrentFlashMode = mFlashAutoSrc;

public FlashButtonView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public FlashButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FlashButtonView, 0, 0));
}

public FlashButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FlashButtonView, 0, defStyleAttr));
}

private void init(TypedArray typedArray) {
    try {
        mFlashAutoSrc = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.FlashButtonView_autoSrcImage);
        mFlashOnSrc = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.FlashButtonView_onSrcImage);
        mFlashOffSrc = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.FlashButtonView_offSrcImage);
    } finally {
        typedArray.recycle();
    }

    setImageDrawable(mFlashAutoSrc);
    mCurrentFlashMode = mFlashAutoSrc;

    setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mCurrentFlashMode == mFlashAutoSrc) {
                setImageDrawable(mFlashOnSrc);
                mCurrentFlashMode = mFlashOnSrc;
            }
            else if(mCurrentFlashMode == mFlashOnSrc){
                setImageDrawable(mFlashOffSrc);
                mCurrentFlashMode = mFlashOffSrc;
            }
            else{
                setImageDrawable(mFlashAutoSrc);
                mCurrentFlashMode = mFlashAutoSrc;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

And this is how my XML looks like:

```
<!--.___ Flash on/off switcher __.-->
<blablabla.FlashButtonView
    custom:autoSrcImage="@drawable/button_autoflash"
    custom:offSrcImage="@drawable/button_noflash"
    custom:onSrcImage="@drawable/button_flash"
    android:id="@+id/flash"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/distance_20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/distance_20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/distance_20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure init is called?

Comment: I am, The button shows correctly. The method onClick it's never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `onTouchEvent()` method. Something like this:

```
float touched_x, touched_y; 
boolean touched = false; 

@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
    touchCounter++; 
    touched_x = event.getX(); 
    touched_y = event.getY(); 
    int action = event.getAction(); 
    switch (action) { 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            touched = true; 
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
            touched = true; 
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            touched = false; 
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: 
            touched = false; 
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE: 
            touched = false; 
            break; default: 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example with:

```
public class CustomButton extends ImageButton {

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init()  {
        this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "ButtonPressed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and they layout:

```
<com.example.bossb.test.CustomButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

works fine for me.